# futurebuilder inside expansiontile flutter

Tags: list, flutter, widget, listtile

I have a screen that consist of `ExpansionTile` and as we know that `ExpansionTile` has `children` property. The thing that I would like to do is I need to catch the trigger `click` of `ExpansionTile`, so when user click the `ExpansionTile` it will run FutureBuilder to get a data from API, is there a way to do that. Because until now... `ExpansionTile` always runs together with the children
Here is part of the code

```
ExpansionTile(
children:[] //here.. I would like to call the data from api, when user click the expansiontile
                                            title: Text(
                                                "${dataAll["data"][i]["lowongan"]}",
                                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                    color: isHovered ||
                                                            listLokerModel.value
                                                                .lokerState[i]
                                                        ? dark_button
                                                        : Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 20)),
                                            subtitle: Text(
                                                "${dataAll["data"][i]["start"]} - ${dataAll["data"][i]["end"]}",
                                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                    color: isHovered ||
                                                            listLokerModel.value
                                                                .lokerState[i]
                                                        ? dark_button
                                                        : Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 16)),
                                            trailing: Icon(
                                              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_sharp,
                                              color: isHovered ||
                                                      listLokerModel
                                                          .value.lokerState[i]
                                                  ? dark_button
                                                  : Colors.white,
                                            ))
```

Comment: Can you share some code as an example?

Comment: `ExpansionTile` has some `on*` callback properties - check the official docs

Comment: @salihgueler I have edited my question, would you like to take a look

Comment: @pskink I have checked it and it has ```onExpansionChanged``` property, I will try it, thank you very much for your information